# Cannot store session as files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. Now I would like to store session as files in a folder. However, it was failed and there was an error message in the log file.

> ERROR - 2018-12-06 14:34:09 --> Cache adapter "file" and backup "apc"
>   are both unavailable. Cache is now using "Dummy" adapter.

My config.php file

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'C:/my/path/to/my/session/files';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

How can I enable cache adapter file? Thank you!

Comment: ensure the session directory is writable/has proper permissions.

Comment: I am now using IIS server and I've granted full permission to IIS_USRS but the error still exists.

Comment: I'm not sure if its related to the problem but the error shown here tells you that the drivers loaded here `$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));` both are unavailable!

Comment: @NAMENO use  a php function to check the folder permissions. is it 775?. you can also try `$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();`